# Calculating an inverse Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I have a pain for a problem... need to find the inverse Laplace transform of:
$$\frac{s^2+s+1}{(s+1)(s+2)^2(s^2+4s+9)}$$
Now, I get that we have to expand the partial fraction, I managed to get to this:
$$\frac{A}{(s+1)}+\frac{B}{(s+2)}+\frac{C}{(s+2)^2}+\frac{Ds+E}{(s^2+4s+9)}$$
and after doing some expanding and simultaneous equations, I got:
$A=\frac{5}{6}$; $B=\frac{64}{5}$; $C=\frac{-67}{5}$; $D=\frac{-289}{30}$; $C=\frac{-347}{10}$
So now, I have
$$\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{(s+1)}+\frac{64}{5}\frac{1}{(s+2)}-\frac{67}{5}\frac{1}{(s+2)^2}-\frac{289}{30}\frac{s}{(s^2+4s+9)}-\frac{347}{10}\frac{1}{(s^2+4s+9)}$$
from here I use the table of inverses in the textbook to get:
$F(s) = \frac{5}{6}e^{-t}+\frac{64}{5}e^{-2t}-\frac{67}{5}te^{-2t}+\dots$
and then I'm stuck on that last polynomial... I have looked and looked but found nothing... and I'm not even sure I did the first part correctly.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$s^2+4s+9=(s+2)^2+(\sqrt{5})^2$$
and take a look at "exponentially decaying
sine/cosine wave" in this [Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms#Table).

P.S. Check your partial fraction decomposition. It should be
$$\frac{1/6}{(s+1)}-\frac{3/5}{(s+2)^2}-\frac{s/6-1/10}{(s^2+4s+9)}
=\frac{1/6}{(s+1)}-\frac{3/5}{(s+2)^2}-\frac{(s+2)/6-13/30}{(s+2)^2+(\sqrt{5})^2}.$$

Comment: yeh I was getting the feel that I had to go down that road, however the table of inverses only showed me:

$\frac{s-a}{(s-a)^{}2+w^{2}} = e^{at}cos(wt)$ and that didnt seem to help me much

Comment: @George Dimitriou  I re-edited my answer. Is it clear now? Any further doubt?

Comment: Hey Robert, I noticed that in your partial fraction decomposition you didn't include:

$\frac{B}{(s+2)}$

why is this?? arent you supposed to include all ascending powers in the denominator from 1-n??

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in this case it turns out  that $B=0$.

Comment: ahh crap, I better check my working, because I'm getting these very large numbers...

Comment: ok, so after checking my working, turns out I was wrong and you were right, b=0...

now after doing a few clacs I get:

$\frac{1}{6}e^{-t}-(\frac{3}{5}+\frac{1}{6}cos\sqrt{5}t+\frac{13}{30}sin\sqrt{5}t)e^{-2t}$

I hope I have it this time...

Comment: The last term should be $\dots -\frac{13}{30\sqrt{5}}\sin\sqrt{5}t)e^{-2t}$